# How to reduce number of computations during d3.js transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So right now, I'm trying to implement a search bar function into my d3.js plot. Right now it doesn't do anything, but that's not the issue at the moment. The problem is that when I type/delete something from the bar, there's visible lag/choppiness in the characters appearing/disappearing. I believe the issue is stemming from my plot. I have 140+ dots moving around the screen, and their position is being interpolated. So from the beginning to the end of the transition, my code has to compute 140 positions thousands of times over.

I've looked into trying to reduce the cardinality of the d3.interpolateNumber function, but it appears that there isn't a third argument to change the number of terms like in a linspace command. Right now I have an array of 1000 numbers for my function to run through, but I don't know how to pass the array to my other functions.

Below are the pertinent functions for this issue. The commented line in tweenPatch is the original code I had that made my code run, but gave my plot computational issues. Variables arr, curr, and step were my attempt to fix the situation, but I haven't been able to figure out how to pass the array into displayPatch().

```
function tweenPatch() {
        var patch = d3.interpolateNumber(1, 26);
        var arr = [];
        var curr = 1;
        var step = (26 - 1) / (1000 - 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            arr.push(curr + (step * i));
        }

        return arr.forEach(function(d) {
            console.log(arr[d]);
            displayPatch(arr[d]);
        });
        //return function(t) { displayPatch(t); };
    }
    function displayPatch(patch) {
        dots.data(interpolateData(patch), function(d) { return d.name; }).call(position).sort(order);
        var inter = Math.floor(patch);
        var seas = 8;
        var patc = 1;
        if (inter > 24) {
            seas = 9;
            patc = inter - 24;
        } else {
            patc = inter;
        }
        label.text("Patch " + seas + "." + patc);
    }

    function interpolateValues(values, number) {
        old = Math.floor(number);
        upd = Math.ceil(number);

        var old_data = values.filter(function(d) {return d.internal == old;});
        var new_data = values.filter(function(d) {return d.internal == upd;});

        var oobj = old_data[0];
        var nobj = new_data[0];

        var onum = oobj[Object.keys(oobj)[4]];
        var nnum = nobj[Object.keys(nobj)[4]];

        var difint = number - old;
        var difdis = 0;
        var newnum = nnum;

        if (nnum > onum) {  
            difdis = nnum - onum;
            newnum = ((difint) * difdis) + onum;
        } else if (onum > nnum) {
            difdis = onum - nnum;
            newnum = onum - ((difint) * difdis);
        }

        return newnum;

    }
```

I believe switching my SVG to a canvas may help things, but since I have no knowledge of canvas I'd rather leave that as a last resort.

Comment: With 140 transitions, canvas won't help that much - the lag isnt the rendering but how you implement the transition. Optimizing should focus on the tween function, can you create a snippet/fiddle that lets us reproduce the problem and/or look for alternative implementations? Alternatively, can you explain the desired transitions mechanics a bit more, and how the code block you have intends to produce the desired result - more context might be useful in answering.